# Run several processes concurrently outputting to different console regions using concurrent-output

Tags: haskell

I'd like to run several processes in parallel while avoiding interleaving output. Using `ConsoleRegion` from the `concurrent-output` package seems to be a good candidate for that, but I don't see a way to start a process and have all output in a console region.

Is it possible to redirect the output of a process to a console region with `concurrent-output`? Or is there some equivalent that allows me to do that?

As mentioned in the comments, there is `createProcessConcurrent`, but that doesn't quite do what I'm trying to do. Given the following code:

```hs
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Concurrent.Async
import Control.Monad
import Data.Functor
import System.Console.ANSI
import System.Console.Concurrent
import System.Console.Regions
import System.Process

run :: IO ()
run = void $ displayConsoleRegions $ do
  mapConcurrently download [1 .. 10]
    `concurrently` createProcessConcurrent (shell "foo.sh")
    `concurrently` createProcessConcurrent (shell "bar.sh")

download :: Int -> IO ()
download n = withConsoleRegion Linear $ \r -> do
  setConsoleRegion r basemsg
  go n r
  where
    basemsg = "Download " ++ show n
    go c r
      | c < 1 = finishConsoleRegion r (basemsg ++ " done!")
      | otherwise = do
          threadDelay 1000000
          appendConsoleRegion r " ... "
          go (c - 1) r
```

And the scripts

```bash
echo "foo"
sleep 1
echo "foo"
sleep 1
echo "foo"
sleep 1
```

```bash
echo "bar"
sleep 1
echo "bar"
sleep 1
echo "bar"
sleep 1
echo "bar"
sleep 1
echo "bar"
sleep 1
```

This is adapted from the docs of `concurrent-output`. The scripts are just simulating some longer running scrips with regular output. What this code does is to print the `download` part regularly (like intended and described in the docs), but it shows the output from the scripts as a whole (which is fine) only after the script has finished (which is not fine).
Instead, I'd like to have a `ConsoleRegion` for each script where the output appears as soon as the script emits it.

Context: I'm trying to build a command line utility similar to the [`git-run` npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/git-run), but running the command for several repositories in parallel

Comment: `createProcessConcurrent` seems like what you need: https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-20.26/concurrent-output-1.10.18/System-Console-Concurrent.html#v:createProcessConcurrent

Comment: @FyodorSoikin thanks for the suggestion, `createProcessConcurrent` does not quite do what I want though. I updated the question with a concrete example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be no built in support for redirecting the output of a process to a region, but it's still possible to add support for it without needing to modify the library. Here's a crude version that I made by copying the implementation of `createProcessConcurrently` and modifying it to output directly to a region instead of buffering. I also made the call blocking for the sake of simplicity, so we don't have to worry about when to close the region etc.

```hs
import Control.Concurrent.Async
import Control.Concurrent
import System.Console.Concurrent
import System.Console.Regions
import System.Process as P
import System.IO (Handle, hClose)
import Control.Monad (void)
import Control.Exception (try, IOException)
import qualified Data.Text.IO as T
import qualified Data.Text as T
import System.Exit (ExitCode)

main = displayConsoleRegions $ do
    mapConcurrently download [20,40..100]
        `concurrently` createProcessWithNewRegion Linear (shell "echo hello 1; sleep 1; echo world 1")
        `concurrently` createProcessWithNewRegion Linear (shell "echo hello 2; sleep 3; echo world 2")
        `concurrently` createProcessWithNewRegion Linear (shell "echo hello 3; sleep 5; echo world 3")

-- | Create a new region and run a process in it. Wait until the process is complete
createProcessWithNewRegion :: RegionLayout
    -> CreateProcess
    -> IO (Either IOException ExitCode)
createProcessWithNewRegion layout = withConsoleRegion layout . bgProcessRegion

-- | Blocking: Create a process and redirect both stdout and stderr to a region
-- when the process is completed, close the region and preserve the output
bgProcessRegion :: CreateProcess -> ConsoleRegion -> IO (Either IOException ExitCode)
bgProcessRegion p reg = do
    let p' = p
            { P.std_out = P.CreatePipe
            , P.std_err = P.CreatePipe
            }
    (stdin_h, stdout_h, stderr_h, h) <- P.createProcess p'
    let r = ( stdin_h , Nothing , Nothing , h)

    -- Send both stdout and stderr to the region
    -- wait until both handles are closed before continuing
    setupOutputBuffer StdOut reg stdout_h
      `concurrently_` setupOutputBuffer StdErr reg stderr_h

    -- If we don't explicitly tell it to save the output,
    -- it will be cleared when the process is done
    finalText <- getConsoleRegion reg
    finishConsoleRegion reg finalText

    -- Wait until the process is terminated
    tryIO (P.waitForProcess h)

-- | Send all text from a handle to a region as soon as it arrives
setupOutputBuffer :: StdHandle -> ConsoleRegion -> Maybe Handle -> IO ()
setupOutputBuffer h reg Nothing = pure ()
setupOutputBuffer h reg (Just fromh) = go
  where
    go = do
        t <- T.hGetChunk fromh
        if T.null t
            then do
                hClose fromh
            else do
                appendConsoleRegion reg t
                go


{- try specialized for IO errors only -}
tryIO :: IO a -> IO (Either IOException a)
tryIO = try


download :: Int -> IO ()
download n = withConsoleRegion Linear $ \r -> do
   setConsoleRegion r basemsg
   go n r
  where
   basemsg = "Download " ++ show n
   go c r
       | c < 1 = finishConsoleRegion r (basemsg ++ " done!")
       | otherwise = do
           threadDelay 100000
           appendConsoleRegion r "."
           go (c-1) r
```